# How to register and set a session variable in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am using a simple script in php to register a session "myusername" on single.php and then using this session on custom.php. I want to convert this script in jQuery so that the whole page(single.php) will not be load.

the php code on single.php is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

session_register("myusername");
}
else{

echo 'other user';

}
```

php code on custom.php is:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){

//redirect
} 
?>
```

The problem is all this takes a lot of time as the page load. I have converted the form in jQuery and redirection as well but problem is just with session create.

I replaced above php code with this jQuery code only problem is creating session:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit1').click(function() {

    var pass = $('#ppassword').val();        

    if ( pass == 'anything') {            
    var url = "http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2";

     $(location).attr('href',url);

// I want to create session here in jQuery

    } else {
        alert('Wrong Password');
        return false;
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Javascript has no direct access to PHP's superglobals, so you can't "convert" PHP code to javascript. You could of course use ajax to run the PHP code without reloading the page.

Comment: Redirection is not the problem that is working but creating session in jquery and using on another page is my question!

Comment: Again, you're using PHP's sessions, and jQuery has no access to those directly. If you just need to store something that doesn't have to be secure for each session you can use sessionStorage or the plugin in the answer below.

Comment: Page won't redirect if you use AJAX. Also, please tag user in your comment, if your comment is meant for someone specific. @user3739733

Comment: Anybody could look at the source code and discover the password is `'anything'`; or simply disable JS. JS runs on the client, so users have full control and you can't impose them a password. You must do that server-side.